# How to get the current test progress while running TestNG from the terminal

Tags: java, logging, testng

When running TestNG from the terminal, an output folder is generated at the end. How do I check the progress mid-run?

All I found are `testrun.log` and `[test_name].log` files, but they don't contain a summary of the progress so far.

Comment: have you configured logging explicitly? using log4j or slf4j in your project.

Comment: If you have not configured logging explicitly in your project then maven build log should show the current test case progress.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to documentation - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging

Any way in general you should add Logger to your test. You can extend your logging using Listener, to output some general info for specific actions - test start and stop, result success or failed.